# Does ownership based sharing rule also shares records of users' subordinates?

Tags: sharing-rule

Sales Manager A has subordinates A1, A2.

Sales Manager B has subordinates B1, B2.

Using ownership based sharing rule, records owned by A are shard with B. Does it also share records owned by A1 and A2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can presume that, Sales Manager A and Sales Manager B are in different roles in Role Hierarchy.

Through Ownership based Sharing rule, using `Roles and Internal Subordinates`, Sales Manager and his subordinates records can be shared to Sales Manager B.

[image: role ownership]

Now, if you are not talking about role based sharing and asking about user based sharing then, question is how you going to share records, either by public groups, queues?

If Sales Manager A and his subordinates are in same public group or queues then all the records owned by them can be shared to Sales Manager B (assuming it is in different group or queues).

By sharing rule, Salesforce doesn't allow individual user and his subordinates (which is identified by Manager field in User record) records to be shared other than that way.

Refer [Record-Level Access: Under the Hood](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood.pdf) for more understanding about this.

Answer (score 1):

Records owned by subordinates A1 and A2 are shared with Manager A through the Role hierarchy. The Manager does not own them.

Roles determine user access to cases, contacts, and opportunities, regardless of who owns those records. Users at any role level can view, edit, and report on all data that’s owned by or shared with users below them in the role hierarchy, unless your Salesforce org’s sharing model for an object specifies otherwise.

The access level is specified on the Role Edit page. You can disable the Grant Access Using Hierarchies option for a custom object. When disabled, only the record owner and users who are granted access by the organization-wide defaults receive access to the object’s records.

Manager A does not directly own the records shared with him through the hierarchy. Manager A can choose to share a record on a record by record basis directly with Manager B that belongs to either of his subordinates A1 or A2 since he has the same access level as his subordinates.

As such, an "owner-based" sharing rule, will only apply directly to the subordinates who actually own the records (A1 or A2), NOT to their Manager A, a "Role-based" or "Group-based" rule would need to be applied instead.